# How to find overlap of two array based of an objects property in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm relatively new to ruby so I'm trying to learn ruby best practices. I have two arrays, `array1` and `array2`. They each only contain a class, `Animal`and each array is guaranteed to be unique individually.  My `Animal` class has among other things a `color` property, which is a string. What I want to do is for each `Animal` in `array1` I want to get all the animals in `array2` with the same color and move that to `array1`. The more verbose code looks as follow:

```
for x from 0 to array1.size
  for y in array2
    if(array1[x].color == y.color)
      array1 << y
      array2.delete(y)
    end
  end
end
```

But seeing that ruby is a very terse language I feel like there is a more elegant solution to do this. What is the most ruby way of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure they contain a class `Animal`? Or, do you mean they contain instances of `Animal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can `select` a set of things from an array (based on whether they match in some given code) eg, say you just wanted to find all animals of a single colour:

```
matching_animals = array2.select {|animal| animal.color == my_color }
```

and in matching animals you have all the animals with `my_color`

if you want all animals that are "any of the colours that are in the first array" then you could do that this way:

```
ok_colors = array1.map{|a| a.color } # pulls out all the colours allowed
matching_animals = array2.select {|animal| ok_colors.include?(animal.color) }
```

now you have a set of matching animals - which you can then add to the original array with:

```
array1 += matching_animals
```

and remove them from the second array with:

```
array2 -= matching_animals
```

Comment: Using this implementation would I still need to use a `for` loop to go through `array1`?

Comment: nope, no for-loop. Instead you're using set-based logic - which is often considered "more rubyish" ;)

Comment: But how do you get `y.color` without looping through `array1`?

Comment: Hmm, you're right... I thought you were looking for all animals of the same colour. But you are asking for any animals of any colour that is already in the first array?

Answer (score 1):

[Edit: My answer is the same as @TayrnEast's, which she posted earlier. I suspect I started work on mine before she did an edit, and I did not notice that edit until now. I'll leave my answer, however, as the example I give may be of interest to some readers.]

I have assumed you want each animal in `array2` moved to `array1` at most once, in which case we would move, say, a "blue" animal from `array2` to `array1` if there is at least one blue animal in `array1`.  If my understanding is correct, you could do it as follows.

**Code**

```
def add_em(array1, array2)
  colors = array1.map(&:color).uniq
  array1 + array2.select { |e| colors.include?(e) }
end
```

**Example**

```
class A
  attr_reader :name, :color
  def initialize(name, color)
    @name = name
    @color = color
  end
end

blackbird  = A.new("blackbird",  :black)
redbird    = A.new("redbird",    :red)
bluebird   = A.new("bluebird",   :blue)

array1 = [blackbird, redbird, bluebird]

orangetoad = A.new("orangetoad", :orange)
bluetoad   = A.new("bluetoad",   :blue)
pinktoad   = A.new("pinktoad",   :pink)
bluemouse  = A.new("bluemounse", :blue)

array2 = [orangetoad, bluetoad, pinktoad, bluemouse]

array1 = add_em(array1, array2)
  #=> [#<A:0x00000101128638 @name="blackbird", @color=:black>,
  #    #<A:0x00000101946b30 @name="redbird", @color=:red>,
  #    #<A:0x00000101120d70 @name="bluebird", @color=:blue>,
  #    #<A:0x00000102102b30 @name="bluetoad", @color=:blue>,
  #    #<A:0x000001020faea8 @name="bluemounse", @color=:blue>]
array1.map(&:name)
  #=> ["blackbird", "redbird", "bluebird", "bluetoad", "bluemounse"]
```

Alternatively, you could change the last line of the method to:

```
  array1 += array2.select { |e| colors.include?(e) }
```

and write:

```
add_em(array1, array2)
array1.map(&:name)
  #=> ["blackbird", "redbird", "bluebird", "bluetoad", "bluemounse"]
```

I prefer the first version because modifying arguments can lead to trouble down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the array documentation:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-collect

```
array1 = array1.map{ do your stuff }

array1.map!{ do your stuff } #this one is inplace...
```